# Triggering data acquisition in Arduino with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I would like to trigger data acquisition on my Arduino UNO with connected accelerometer (MPU 6050) by using Python. 
The idea is that when the command is given in Python, the Arduino would start saving data on its SRAM and when a certain number of measurements would be saved, the data would be sent in a package back to Python.

This is my current Arduino code:

```
#include<Wire.h>
#define MPU6050_DLPF_94HZ     MPU6050_DLPF_CFG_2

const int MPU_addr_1 = 0x68; // I2C address of the first MPU-6050
const int baudrate = 19200;
int16_t AcX1; // definition of variables

const int len = 200; // Buffer size
float analogDataArray[len];
int count = 0;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr_1);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(baudrate);
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr_1);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr_1, 8, true); // request a total of 14 registers
  float AcX1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)


  if (Serial.available())
  {
    if (Serial.read() == 'Y') {
      analogDataArray[count] = AcX1;
      count = count + 1;
      if (count >= len) {
        for (int i; i <= len; i = i + 1) {
          Serial.println(analogDataArray[i] / 16384);
        }
      }
      count = 0;

    }
  }
  delay(5);
}
```

and this is my Python code:

```
import serial
arduinoData = serial.Serial('COM3', 19200)
com = input('Press "Y":' )
arduinoData.write(bytes(com, 'utf-8'))

vec = []

run = True
while run is True:
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting() == 0):
        pass
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline()
    vec.append(float(arduinoString))
    if len(vec) >= 100:
        run = False
print(vec)
```

I've managed to get it working for 1 measurement but as soon as I defined an array inside Arduino to save multiple measurements, the code doesn't work. I'm sure that it is close to working, but I can't find the detail that is stopping me from that.

Thank you for any provided help.
Kind regards,

L

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, the problem was in my Arduino code, as expected.

```
#include<Wire.h>
#define MPU6050_DLPF_94HZ     MPU6050_DLPF_CFG_2

const int MPU_addr_1 = 0x68; // I2C address of the first MPU-6050
const int baudrate = 9600;
int16_t AcX1; // definition of variables

const int len = 200; // Buffer size
float analogDataArray[len];
int count = 0;

int ans;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr_1);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(baudrate);
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr_1);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr_1, 8, true); // request a total of 14 registers
  float AcX1 = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)


  if (Serial.available() && Serial.read() == 'Y') {
    ans = 1;
  }
  if (ans == 1) {
    analogDataArray[count] = AcX1;
    count = count + 1;
    if (count >= len) {
      for (int i; i <= len; i = i + 1) {
        Serial.println(analogDataArray[i] / 16384);
      }
      ans = 0;
    }
  }
  delay(5);
}
```